# how static integer variable in java assign default zero

Tags: java

My question is: how to assign *default zero* to an static integer variable?

This is my code:

```
class Point {
    static int i;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("" + i);
    }
}
```

The output must be:

`0`

Answer (score 5):

All class level numbered `primitives` will be initialized to `0`.

All class level `Objects` will be initialized to `null`;

Other default values are

```
byte    0
char    '\u0000'
boolean false
```

Comment: instead you can say to their default value.

Comment: short, int, long, float, double,char, byte are primitives - they are not Objects.

Comment: Not entirely true though: `boolean` defaults to `false` and `char` defaults to `\u0000`. Also, not only class level, but also local variables default to 0, null, false and `\u0000`

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong Local primitive variables do **not** default to `0`

Comment: @user2310289 If I could double upvote, I would. Now that you say it, it indeed comes to mind that local vars do not get initialized. My mistake, thanks for reminding.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong Your comment is very generous - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `i`  is an integer it allocates the [`default value`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to `zero`

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.

```
byte    0
short   0
int 0
long    0L
float   0.0f
double  0.0d
char    '\u0000'
String (or any object)      null
boolean false
```

This happened only if you are doing at class level
         If it is a local variable,you have to initalize before you use. Otherwise compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

Class' primitive members (static or non-static) are set with default value as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

`int` values are set to `0` by default.